# Scheduling a python script with Windows task scheduler

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

**Overview of the setup:**

- W10 professional within a domain
- All scripts and files within 1 folder (not local but network drives connected to the file server)
- 2 python scripts: one to filter an Excel file (removing columns and stuff), another to edit an HTML file and fill it with the content of the excel file.

**The scripts** (they work perfectly, no errors or problems so no debug needed but maybe the path references are causing my main problem that I'll explain in the lower part of this post/question):

- The script to convert 1 excel file to another to filter data uses following main path references:

Reading the excel:

```
 df = pd.read_excel('H:\python codes\excel\planner software\planning-update.xls')
```

Write it:

```
df.to_excel('H:\python codes\excel\planner software\planning-update-filtered.xlsx', index=False)
```

start the next python script that creates/edits the html file:

```
subprocess.call(["python", "H:\python codes\excel\planner software\make-website.py"])
```

- The script to read the excel, opens the html, edits the html uses the same "read" reference for excel as above and uses this one to open the html:

Open html:

```
open("H:\python codes\excel\planner software\calendar.html", "w") as f:
```

**The goal:**
The goal is to automate the first script and let it run everyday at a specific hour. It should be done if the user is logged in or logged out. It shouldn't matter. I try to do this with windows task scheduler.

**What I tried:**

I created a task within the task scheduler. I selected the box to run the task no matter the login status of the user. Within Action is chose for "start program", for program/script i put in the storage path "\storage\Users\lambra\python codes\excel\planner software\planner.py" and in the start in field, i put "\storage\Users\lambra\python codes\excel\planner software"

I did this following other stackoverflow posts and google findings. I tried it with drive letters as well. Sometimes my settings where setup that the task scheduler gave an error that it could not run the task. However with these settings, it says it ran the task but I notice the HTML file is not changed. In task scheduler I can see that the task is started (event ID 100), the editing is started (ID 200) and I get a line with

> task started by user (ID 110)

I already tried to change all permissions to allow everything for those files. When running the python script manually or even with a batch file, it works, but scheduling it, does not.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue once, and came up with a workaround since it seems TS is not python friendly.
Now what I use Task Scheduler to run a .bat file that executes the python programs one after the other.

**The file should look like this:**

run_from_TS.bat

```
:: Open the disk where you store your program
D:
:: Open the project folder for your python scripts
cd "D:/path/to/project"
:: Open the python script you want to execute using the correct python instance
"D:\path\to\project\Environment\Scripts\python.exe" "D:\path\to\script\to\run"
```

Please note that i use "/" and "".

**On the TS the options are as follows:**
General: Run with highest privileges is DISABLED.
Triggers: Whenever you want, but make sure Status is Enabled.
Actions: Start a program (path to your .bat file following this example and using "": "D:\the\path\to\file.bat").
Conditions: Your choice here.
Settings: Your choice here. I recommend enabling "Allow task to be run on demand".

PD:
I would also recommand you to familiarize yourself on how .bat and TS work (togheter) before running your scripts. Remember you can enable the task to be run on demand on the TS settings as mentioned above and test if it is not working from the TS part or the .bat part.

PD 2 (my TS config):
[image: General settings]

[image: Triggers]

[image: Actions]

[image: Conditions]

[image: Settings]

Comment: Ok i followed your instructions but no results. I do however have 2 questions:
The .bat file (open the disk where you store your program): My bat file and python are on different drives, should i open them both? I did notice the different kind of slashes and followed the instruction, however in Actions on the scheduler, i also need to put in a path, how should this path be written?

The task scheduler says the tasks is done, can i add something in the bat file to get a log to know if there are errors or stuff? thanks for your help btw!

Comment: Okay so first: the path should be written as follows "D:\the\path\to\file.bat", don't forget the ""! And second: YES, open both disk first, and if one is an external one (server) make sure your PC has it registered (for example setting a path to S:/...). And I would recommend having both files on the same disk... That means maybe bringing the python script to your local PC but have it access data on another disk, but it should be python the one to handle this operation, not the TS or the .bat file.

Comment: Ok, changed it but no results. task scheduler thinks it executed the task so i think i need to have something in my bat file that gives me a sign that it has ran by task scheduler..

Comment: Try adding this line on top of your .bat: ECHO "THIS IS A TEST". And this at the end: PAUSE. As a debuging tool, what happens?

Comment: BTW, an upvote woudn't hurt. Stuck so low I can't vote anything...

Comment: Hi Apiuser, thank you for your time. I did add the pause and the echo. When running the .bat directly, i get the cmd screen with the echo and the pause. The python runs great. When running the task in scheduler i do not get a cmd screen.

Comment: i found ou the problem is in the general tab with safety options. When "only run if user is logged in" is checked, it works. It does not work when i check the other one. The user account i tried for this are: domain admin, local admin, local user, domain user. none did the trick for me

Comment: Glad to see it worked out at the end. Yes, TS sucks a lot...

Comment: it still does not work when logged off so i still need to solve this problem. If TS sucks a lot, is there another tool that allows this within a domain?

Comment: I don't know of another program in windows that could do the job...
Try this bat: 
line 1: ECHO "THIS IS A TEST", line 2: PAUSE
Now try disabling all privileges of the job and try to run this job the next minute until you hit a combination that works for you. For me what worked was what I posted on the answer. I will update them, so check them out agian.